# CSS pseudo element positioning - partial border above header

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am struggling to position the partial border directly above the title without the title floating to the left of the 'before' pseudo element.  It works fine on pages without an image but I need the title and text to wrap around the image on some pages where an image exists but not on others and this is causing the issue.

I have tried absolute positioning, different displays but nothing works.

https://codepen.io/lol4000/pen/dyZvmGK

```
 <img width="420" height="195" src="https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="PIM" srcset="https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS.jpg 420w, https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS-300x139.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 420px) 100vw, 420px">            <h2 class="sub-title">Test English subtitle</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacinia porta velit, ornare lobortis tortor aliquam at. Vivamus tristique, nulla vitae tempus vehicula, ante arcu lobortis est, nec maximus nunc ipsum et nunc.</p> <p>Donec mattis vulputate tellus, vel tincidunt purus condimentum vel. </p>Cras vehicula, ex non varius faucibus, felis orci consectetur dui, vitae auctor lectus ex ornare ligula. Maecenas nec lectus turpis. <p>In varius ligula eu leo rhoncus fringilla. Nullam blandit iaculis cursus. Sed pulvinar sollicitudin rhoncus. </p><p>Pellentesque vulputate luctus ante non luctus. Integer tincidunt, tellus at maximus fermentum, lorem ante sagittis elit, in varius dui nulla et est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer eget nunc nec augue congue vestibulum. Vestibulum id libero enim.</p> <p>Etiam vulputate efficitur erat a viverra. Mauris eu malesuada lacus. Sed vestibulum est in velit euismod, quis porttitor velit rhoncus.</p><p>Pellentesque vulputate luctus ante non luctus. Integer tincidunt, tellus at maximus fermentum, lorem ante sagittis elit, in varius dui nulla et est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer eget nunc nec augue congue vestibulum. Vestibulum id libero enim.</p> <p>Etiam vulputate efficitur erat a viverra. Mauris eu malesuada lacus. Sed vestibulum est in velit euismod, quis porttitor velit rhoncus.</p>

h2.sub-title {font-size:28px;display: block;}
h2.sub-title::before{ position: relative; height: 8px;width: 130px;left: 0;  top: -10px;background: #441A6D;display:block;content: ""}


.wp-post-image {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 10px 0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Ok, so we use `display: inline-block;` in heading to properly define the role of the box in the page, which is inline. Since there is no wrapper element in our content, we do not need to do anything else (except the relative and absolute positioning). Also, I used the `float: left;` on the img since we want img to be on the far left and the rest of the content overflow in its right.

```css
h2.sub-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2.sub-title::before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  width: 130px;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  background: #441A6D;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

img {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <h2 class="sub-title">Test English subtitle</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacinia porta velit, ornare lobortis tortor aliquam at. Vivamus tristique, nulla vitae tempus vehicula, ante arcu lobortis est, nec maximus nunc ipsum et nunc.</p>
  <p>Donec mattis vulputate tellus, vel tincidunt purus condimentum vel. </p>Cras vehicula, ex non varius faucibus, felis orci consectetur dui, vitae auctor lectus ex ornare ligula. Maecenas nec lectus turpis.
  <p>In varius ligula eu leo rhoncus fringilla. Nullam blandit iaculis cursus. Sed pulvinar sollicitudin rhoncus. </p>
  <p>Pellentesque vulputate luctus ante non luctus. Integer tincidunt, tellus at maximus fermentum, lorem ante sagittis elit, in varius dui nulla et est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer eget nunc nec augue congue vestibulum. Vestibulum id libero
    enim.
  </p>
  <p>Etiam vulputate efficitur erat a viverra. Mauris eu malesuada lacus. Sed vestibulum est in velit euismod, quis porttitor velit rhoncus.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque vulputate luctus ante non luctus. Integer tincidunt, tellus at maximus fermentum, lorem ante sagittis elit, in varius dui nulla et est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer eget nunc nec augue congue vestibulum. Vestibulum id libero
    enim.
  </p>
  <p>Etiam vulputate efficitur erat a viverra. Mauris eu malesuada lacus. Sed vestibulum est in velit euismod, quis porttitor velit rhoncus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is another great answer but unfortunaltey I have text as well as the title that needs to wrap around the image if theree is one. Flex puts it all in columns and the float options float the text to the left of the title. Sorry I should have added some text to the example, I have added your solution with the text in the codepen.

Comment: @LeeTee no problem, I'm updating my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex` instead `float`:

```css
h2.sub-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  display: block;
}

h2.sub-title::before {
  position: relative;
  height: 8px;
  width: 130px;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  background: #441A6D;
  display: block;
  content: ""
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

.wp-post-image {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div><img width="420" height="195" src="https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="PIM" srcset="https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS.jpg 420w, https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS-300x139.jpg 300w"
    sizes="(max-width: 420px) 100vw, 420px">
  <h2 class="sub-title">Test English subtitle</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Its a great solution but unfortunaltey I have text as well as the title and flex puts it all in columns.  Sorry I should have added some text to the example.

Comment: @LeeTee Thanks. no problem. this is important that George's answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the text to go to the bottom of the photo, you used this method and the h2 tag covers the entire container, so the first h2 is the beginning of the photo.

```
h2.sub-title {font-size:28px;display: block;position: relative;}
h2.sub-title::before{ position: absolute; height: 8px;width: 130px;left: 0;  top: -10px;background: #441A6D;display:block;content: ""}
```

Get `width` and `margin-right` img by JavaScript and set to style left ::before, and
before is absolute

Comment: I dont want the text at the bottom, I need it to float to the left.  Surley this can be done with just CSS?

Comment: Please include your code in a snippet or a `code block`. Also, since OP is asking for a CSS solution, solving the issue with JavaScript should be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, I've created an alternate solution rather than pesudo element. please check it out and let me know.

```css
.image-text{display: flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.heading{posittion: relative;}
h2.sub-title {font-size:28px;position: relative;}
.border{ position: relative; height: 8px;width: 130px; top: 17px;background: #441A6D; display: inline-block; }


.wp-post-image {
    margin: 0 15px 10px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="image-text"> 
  <div class="image"><img width="420" height="195" src="https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="PIM" srcset="https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS.jpg 420w, https://heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Fotolia_50400145_XS-300x139.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 420px) 100vw, 420px"> 
  </div>
  <div class="heading">
    <span class="border"></span>
    <h2 class="sub-title">Test English subtitle</h2>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As this <h2> tag will be added throughout  content in wordpress its not possible to write this markup every time